# Verifying sequence of repeatedly typed charecters in an MS Excel

Tags: excel

I need to find the errors in the sequence of charecters that are typed repeatedly.  If the charecter typed in a wrong sequence then the previous and next sequence will also be an error. (as like highlighted in yellow in the picture).
=IF(A1="A" AND A2="B" AND A3="A",1, 0) - This I believe works for only first three rows, this has to be repeated till end of the rows.

Kindly suggest.

Sequence - 
A
B
A
B
A
B

Error sequence (charecter highlighted in bold) -
A
B
A
B
A
B
**B** 
A 
B
A
**A** 
B

[image: Sample data and errors highlighted in yellow]

Comment: What have you actually tried to get it to work?

Comment: Hi @Scott Holtzman, Thanks for responding, I have tried this =IF(A1="A" AND A2="B" AND A3="A",1, 0), but this works only for first 3 rows, how to check this repeated till the end of the rows?  Is where I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the sequence you've also done with formula, then the error status is only determined by the column typed charecters. Asumming that is col A.
the formula of error col. should be

```
=IF(A2=A1,1,0)
```

Drag the formula to the bottom

Comment: Thanks Anabas for responding, however, the consecutive rows may not be equal when a user type if you see the 5th row from below it, has "C", so the proposed formula will not work in this case.

Comment: So you just want it to keep ABABABAB...mode? Do not accept ABABACAC? A & B is fixed?

Comment: PLEASE advise ABABABABAAB is 1 or 0, I think it shuold be 0, where you marked it as 1.

Comment: It should follow the sequence A-B-A-B-A... if there is mistyped character then Error column should capture as an error (1)

Comment: `=N(NOT((IF(MOD(ROW(),2),"B","A")=A2)))` Then it means even row (col. A) is always equal to "A", while odd row is "B", it can keep ABABABAB (01010101)

Comment: I have got it with a minor change - =N(NOT((IF(MOD(ROW(),2),"A","B")=A1))).  Thanks Anabas for the help.